# "Здравствуйте вам" - присказка или приветствие? Как ответить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте вам... Так говорят, и нередко. Присказка ли, приветствие? Что за конструкция, как она выглядит на бумаге?

Comment: Банальное просторечие. давайте ещё спинджак обсудим и полуклинику.

Answer (score 2):

Это фамильярное, дружеское приветствие, допустимое в неформальном общении довольно близких  людей.

А сама конструкция - усечённый вариант предложения "Моё вам здравствуйте". Думаю, что знаков никаких не требуется. Предложение по типу "Привет вам!"

В соответстии со стилем высказывания допустИм, на мой взгляд,  ответ " И вам здравствуйте!", а также "И вам не болеть!" Такой же, как ответ на пожелание "Будьте здоровы!"

Comment: Или "И вам не хворать".

Answer (score 2):

"Моё вам здравствуйте", как тут уже было сказано.
А вот еще одно сокращение:

*— А-а-а... мое вам! — зевает фельдшер. — С чем пожаловали?*

(А.П. Чехов. "Хирургия")

Answer (score 1):

Для приветствия это излишне просторечно (обычные формы обращения к группе людей: "здравствуйте все" или "всем - здравствуйте"). Больше похоже на восклицания "здрасте пожалуйста!" и "нате вам!". Есть фильм с таким названием, причём "Вам" - с заглавной (выглядит как подчёркнутое обращение к кому-то из группы), но чего только не бывает в киношно-художественном смысле! Ответное приветствие в такой ситуации означало бы согласие с тем, что остальным присутствующим можно преспокойно болеть. Поэтому речь некоторых литературных персонажей - не повод для потакания таким манерам. Я бы растерялся с ответом.

Comment: Там ещё и знаки в наличие: "Здравствуйте, Вам!". Так на постере значится. В поиске можно встретить все возможные варианты, -  до прописного. Интересно то, что в самом фильме титула нет (до 20 минуты ждал), Видно, из-за трудностей перевода на русский письменный.

Comment: Очевидно не приветственное, ситуативное «Здрасте вам! Приехали!» синонимично фразе о медном тазе или знаменитому киношному «Ку-ку, Гриня!».